# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una función publica que permita escribir un nombre, extraiga el primer carácter y lo ponga en mayúscula? C#

Tags: c#, string, caracteres, substring

Lo que me quiero conseguir es, si el nombre es pepe por ejemplo, seria P.Pepe

```
string Name { get; set; }
        public void Mensaje()
        {            
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: ");
            Name = (Console.ReadLine());            


            Console.WriteLine(" Mensaje de " + Name.ToString() + "." + Name.ToString()); ;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un `Substring(0,1)` del nombre y después concatenarlo con la parte restante del nombre. Para convertir de `pepe` a `Pepe`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public string PrimeraLetraAMayus(string texto)
        {
            string resul = texto.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + texto.Substring(1);
            return resul;
            // Recibe como parámetro en texto el nombre "pepe" y devuelve "Pepe"
        }
```

En cambio si lo que quieres es que convierta de `pepe` a `P.Pepe`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public string PrimeraLetraAMayus(string texto)
        {
            string resul = texto.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + "." + texto.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + texto.Substring(1);
            return resul;
            // Recibe como parámetro en texto el nombre "pepe" y devuelve "P.Pepe"
        }
```

Lo que en ambos casos, el método recibe como parámetro el texto que queremos convertir con la primera a mayúsculas y hace es lo siguiente:

- Con `Substring(0,1)` nos coge el primer carácter, de la posición `0`, que es el primer carácter del texto a la posición `1` sin incluir. Despues, utilizamos el método `ToUpper()` para que nos convierta esa letra a mayúsculas.
- Seguidamente lo que hacemos es concatenarle la parte restante con `Substring(1)` que nos coge desde la posición `1` del nombre hasta el final.

Answer (score -1):

El codigo final seria

```
string name { get; set; }
public void Mensaje()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre: ");
        name = (Console.ReadLine());
        string Nombre = name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + "." + name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Mensaje de " + Nombre.ToString() + ".");
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).